# Refresh php script on submit

Tags: php, post, refresh

i have a question on a short php script here. I have created a script to edit a txt file, the script works just fine, no problem with it. Im trying to make the script reload automaticaly on submit and im really stack here.

Here is the script:

```
<?
if($_POST['Submit']){
$open = fopen("../youtubelink.txt","w+");
$text = $_POST['update'];
fwrite($open, $text);
fclose($open); 
$file = file("../youtubelink.txt");
foreach($file as $text) {
echo $text."<br />";
}
}else{
$file = file("../youtubelink.txt");
echo "<form action=\"".$PHP_SELF."\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<textarea Name=\"update\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"10\">";

foreach($file as $text) {
echo $text;
} 

echo "</textarea>";
echo "<input name=\"Submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\" />\n
</form>";

}

?>
```

Any help please?

Comment: reload automatically? you mean the contents of the page without actually refreshing the page or something?

Answer (score 0):

use Ajax and query every x Minutes a script that checks the text file for changes. If the Ajax returns "yes, updates available" reload the page with Javascript.